# Display view page informations in tabs

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view, tabs

We are using below 2 parts of code in view.phtml to display result in [**product view page**](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/beer-is-what-makes-you-see-double-and-feel-single-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html).

now Part 2 [ **Features** ] result is displaying below Part1 [ **Product Description** ]. I want to display these 2 parts as tabs in view page, so that if we click on particular tab, that part should open.

[image]

**Part 1**

```
<div>

<h1>Product Description </h1>
<?php echo $_product->getDescription();?>

<div>

<h1>Product Size & Space <span class="hidden-sku"><?php echo $_product->getSku();?></span> </h1>
<?php echo $attribute_value = $_product->getData('size_space');?>

</div>                               
</div>
```

**Part 2**

```
<div>
<div>

<?php echo $attribute_value = $_product->getData('interior_exterior');?>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Summing up, you need a tab system correct?

Comment: you are right @Paul

Comment: Do you use jQuery @BabyinMagento?

Comment: @Paul i did't used any `jquey` code until now for this feature.

Comment: Check my answer below @BabyinMagento

Comment: It's magento 1.9 default functionality. Do you use magento default one or use third party?

Comment: @SohelRana we are using 1.9 , we are not using any custom code. before other devoloper was working, so he removed tabs i guess. how i can display it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code you need, replace the tabs content with what you need and style however you want.

Sample: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nuhfve3L/)

[VIEW CODE HERE](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwBDd-82dSoSOWYxRjY1cVJqS3c) or in JSFiddle above

Let me  know if this worked fine for you! I've tested it.

Comment: first tab working fine, second tab is not displaying any information.

Comment: when i used jsfiddle code, it worked fine. Thanks a lot....

Comment: @BabyinMagento you welcome, glad I could help!